# The specified child already has a parent

Tags: android, android-webview

I don't know what is happening. My code is crashing and I dont find the reason.

I've a LinearLayout which is a container of several WebViews.

```
LinearLayout variableContent = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.variableContent);
for (int i=0; i<5;i++){
    XMLModule modul = modulsRecuperats.get(i);
    myWebView webview = new myWebView(this);
    WebView customWebViewContainer = (WebView) this.mInflater.inflate(R.layout.customwebview, null);
    customWebViewContainer = webview._clientSettings(customWebViewContainer,progressDialog);
    customWebViewContainer.loadData(modul.getContent(), "text/html", "UTF-8");
    variableContent.addView(customWebViewContainer);
}
```

And the code crashes when addView is called. With this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

I can't find a reason. Can you help me out?

Comment: it looks like your variableContent already has some content. You could  do a variableContent.removeView() and then call the for loop.

Comment: But that has no sense, because a linear layout is a layout which can contain several childs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `customWebViewContainer` already has a parent. A `View` cannot have 2 parents, so this exception is thrown. I can only assume that the call to `webview._clientSettings()` is wrapping that view with another container.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please post the class "myWebView"? In particular the method _clientSettings would be needed so that we know what is going on there.